# How to compare 2 2-D histograms and get the probability of the 2 being the same / having samples drawn from the same/very similar distributions?

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, histogram

I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499491/comparing-two-histograms) describing methods of comparing histograms and in particular bin-to-bin comparison and cross-bin comparison and want to know how to use these to numerically evaluate how well the 2 2D histograms match?

I have provided an example below of generating and plotting 2 similar histograms and 2 different histograms to which I would like to apply these methods of comparison.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import ndtest
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

N = 5000

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, [N])
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, [N])

x1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, [N])
y1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, [N])

x2 = np.random.normal(0.5, 1, [N])
y2 = np.random.normal(0, 2, [N])

nbins = 50

LIMS = [[-4, 4],
        [-4, 4]]
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=nbins,range=LIMS, density=True)
xcentres = xedges[0:-1] + xedges[0:-1] - xedges[1:]
ycentres = yedges[0:-1] + yedges[0:-1] - yedges[1:]
H = H/np.sum(H)

LIMS = [[-4, 4],
        [-4, 4]]
H1, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x1, y1, bins=nbins,range=LIMS, density=True)
xcentres = xedges[0:-1] + xedges[0:-1] - xedges[1:]
ycentres = yedges[0:-1] + yedges[0:-1] - yedges[1:]
H1 = H1/np.sum(Hsim)

# if I plot the 2 you can see they look similar
plt.imshow(H)
plt.imshow(H1)
```

[image]
[image]

```
LIMS = [[-4, 4],
        [-4, 4]]
H2, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2, y2, bins=nbins,range=LIMS, density=True)
xcentres = xedges[0:-1] + xedges[0:-1] - xedges[1:]
ycentres = yedges[0:-1] + yedges[0:-1] - yedges[1:]
H2 = H2/np.sum(Hsim)

# if I then plot these 2 you can see they look very different
plt.imshow(H)
plt.imshow(H2)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your link doesn't link to the post you mentioned. Alternatively, you can take a look at this paper: www2.stat.duke.edu/~lm186/files/MRS_preprint.pdf (section 2.6 and Figure 6 discuss 2D problems). The accompanying `R` package is called `MRS`.

Comment: I've fixed the broken link. Thanks, I'll take a look.